# SimpleOpenNI error while opening .oni file in Processing 2.2.1

Tags: java, processing, kinect, simple-openni

I am trying to open an .oni file to test some stuff without having a Kinect connected to my computer. I've used one of the examples provided with SimpleOpenNI (the SimpleOpenNI DepthImage Test) and some code I found on stackoverflow: [How to read oni file in Processing 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044116/how-to-read-oni-file-in-processing-2)

The error is:

```
NullPointerException

SimpleOpenNI Error: Can't open device:      DeviceOpen 
     using default: no devices found
```

Technically, when no device is found, it should just open up the file, but I can't figure out why it doesn't happen that way.

I am using Processing 2.2.1 and the SimpleOpenNI 1.9.6 library for Processing, along with OpenNI on Windows 7 x64. OpenNI seems to be ok, as its reader can open .oni files. The problem seems to be somewhere in Processing, but I can't figure it out. Is there a way to make Processing work without connecting a Kinect to my computer, just by opening .oni files? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think they talk about the same issue in this thread:
[SimpleOpenNI Record and Replay User Tracking Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534014/simpleopenni-record-and-replay-user-tracking-data)

Seems there is an issue with the current way SimpleOpenNI (v1.96) records the data.
IN the thread they say if you use ONI files that were recorded with v0.27 the playback works.